# display post from html in following php script

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a html page that posts to mysql database through a php script. How do I get the information that was entered in the html page to display after 1 record created?

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('****', '****', '****', 'orders');

$sequence = $_POST['sequence'];
$items_count = $_POST['items_count'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];

$sql="INSERT INTO orders (sequence,items_count,total,payment_type)
VALUES
('$sequence','$items_count','$total','$payment_type')";

if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
echo '1 record created';

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: You can make use of [`sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) (if you know how to handle that with sessions) --- And do use prepared statements, your code is prone to [`SQL injection`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities... enjoy having your sever pwn3d.

Comment: I highly recommend you use an ORM like idiorm -- it'll make your life much easier as you are learning these things : https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm

Comment: Thank you Fred and Marc for pointing me in the right direction and trying to save my server. I dont have it working yet, but Ill get there. Side note: should I stick with mysqli or convert to PDO. I'm seeing mysqli can be made secure, but which is the safer way to go?

Answer (score 1):

In the page that is supposed to display the posts, have another query

```
$sql = "SELECT sequence,items_count,total,payment_type FROM orders";
```

and I'm not sure if it's the right mysqli function, but after you retrieve the data from mysql as an array (mysqli_fetch_array ?) - you have to iterate through the returned results.

```
foreach($fetched_row as $row){ 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>"
}
```

Which, you'll obviously want to use your own HTML - and the `$row` will be an associative array with the column names as the keys --

Comment: I think foreach loop is not required for just one record because only the last inserted record is needed to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code on the page where your fields will be displayed.

```
<?php
$last_record_id = mysql_insert_id();
$query = "SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <$table_primary_key_id> = '$last_record_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
?>
```

Then fetch each field in separate variable like $price = $row['price'] and display them. You don't need looping because there is only one record to fetch and display.

Comment: Don't use asterisks -